# Flutter - Column that takes the height of its children

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to arrange children vertically in a way that the parent will take the size of its children?

More specifically, here's what I'm trying to do:

Have an icon and a text aligned vertically with a small space between them, centered within a rectangle with a fixed height.

I'd like the size of the vertical container of the text and icon to be according to its children.
Something like FlatButton.icon, only vertical instead of horizontal.

For that inner vertical container, all I found were Column and ListView, both of which take all the height they can get within their parent, rather than take the height of their children.

[image: Mockup]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sample code should do the job :

```
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Container(
                child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.star,
                              size: 50.0,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 30,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Some text',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        width: 120)),
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                color: Colors.green),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Thanks to the mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

Comment: I completely forgot about this property. Thanks.